# Save shapes on the last frame of video opencv

Tags: python, opencv

For each frame of the video, I am drawing a rectangle and a circle around the object that I am detecting. I want to save and draw all the shapes that were drawn throughout the loop onto the last frame of the video. Sort of like saving an image that has the trajectory of the object throughout the video. I don't know how to achieve this. Any advice would be appreciated.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Open the video
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('v.mp4')


while(1):
    success, frame = cap.read()
    # Take each frame
    if success:
        crop_img = frame[200:2000, 400:2500].copy()   
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(crop_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp=1.5, minDist=505,param1=75, param2=30, minRadius=8, maxRadius=30)

        # ensure at least some circles were found
        if circles is not None:
            # convert the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles to integers
            circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")
            # loop over the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles
            for (x, y, r) in circles:
                print(x,y)
    
                # draw the circle in the output image, then draw a rectangle
                # corresponding to the center of the circle
                cv2.circle(crop_img, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 0), 4)
                cv2.rectangle(crop_img, (x - 5, y - 5),
                            (x + 5, y + 5), (0, 128, 255), -1)
        
        cv2.imshow('hi', crop_img)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
    else:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Define a `list`, append the circles. For last frame, iterate over the `list` and draw all of them. Or, define a numpy `zeros`, add the `circle` to the numpy array, lastly add the frame and the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Open the video
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('0.mp4')

circles_all = []
```

I had added `circles_all` list to store all circles that you detected.

```
while True:
    success, new_frame = cap.read()
    # Take each frame
    if success:
        frame = new_frame
        crop_img = frame[200:2000, 400:2500].copy()
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(crop_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp=1.5, minDist=505, param1=75, param2=30, minRadius=8,
                                   maxRadius=30)

        # ensure at least some circles were found
        if circles is not None:
            # convert the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles to integers
            circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")
            # loop over the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles
            for x, y, r in circles:
                print(x, y)
                circles_all.append([x, y, r])
                # draw the circle in the output image, then draw a rectangle
                # corresponding to the center of the circle
                cv2.circle(crop_img, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 0), 4)
                cv2.rectangle(crop_img, (x - 5, y - 5),
                              (x + 5, y + 5), (0, 128, 255), -1)

        cv2.imshow('hi', crop_img)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Then added `circles_all.append` to append coords and radius.

After that when no more frames, you iterate trought `circles_all` and save image.

```
    else:
        for (x, y, r) in circles_all:
            # draw the circle in the output image, then draw a rectangle
            # corresponding to the center of the circle
            cv2.circle(frame, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 0), 4)
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x - 5, y - 5),
                          (x + 5, y + 5), (0, 128, 255), -1)
        cv2.imwrite('lastframe.jpg', frame)
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Final efect is like this for ten frames.
[image]

Comment: Hi there, thank you so much for the solution. I got this error though:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mingaioh/Desktop/t/s.py", line 42, in <module>
    cv2.imwrite('./lastframe.jpg', frame)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) /private/var/folders/nz/vv4_9tw56nv9k3tkvyszvwg80000gn/T/pip-req-build-yaf6rry6/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:753: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'imwrite'

Comment: tried printing the last "frame", it outputted "none"

Comment: Sorry, I forgotten that when video ends there is no frame to read, I modified answer, check begin of `while True`

Comment: Yes. it worked! But I wonder what the  I += 1 if i > 10: continue Is for?

Comment: I added this to not wait for entire video to goes to end and forgot to delete this, it's unnecessary.